# Javascript API - getting undefined for an optional js sdk module

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with an api, their docs can be found [here](http://techdocs.spid.no/sdks/js/api-docs/#get-logout-uri). Since I am using the link for login and logout from their systems, I would like to use the option of redirecting users back to my website. In their docs it says:

> The SPiD.Uri module is separated from the main JS SDK, and is
>   optional. It's assigned to the global variable SPiD_Uri when using the
>   vanilla JS variant. The SPiD.Uri module is also available as with AMD
>   on CommonJS packaging.

And that functions for redirecting users are:

```
SPiD_Uri.login(redirectUri, clientId);
SPiD_Uri.logout(redirectUri, clientId);
```

I am using cdn for their sdk:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.spid.se/sdk/spid-sdk-2.1.0-var.js"></script>
```

And then in my function I am trying to redirect users the same way it is suggested in the docs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var redirectUri = 'http://mywebsite.no/';
  var clientId = 'someRandomNumber';

  //Initiate SDK
  SPiD.init({
    client_id: clientId,
    server: 'identity-pre.schibsted.com',
  });

  SPiD_Uri.login(redirectUri, clientId);
  SPiD_Uri.logout(redirectUri, clientId);
});
```

But, I get an error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: SPiD_Uri is not defined ReferenceError:
>   SPiD_Uri is not defined

Comment: Could you put this on codepen or jsbin so that we can see where you are loading in the resources etc?

Comment: I found an link for the optional part, another script needs to be called, I will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to manipulate redirections you need to also call the script responsible for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.spid.se/sdk/spid-uri-2.1.0-var.js"></script>
```